# Combining two mesh functions

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &},
 MeshShading -> {Red, Yellow},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ViewPoint -> {3.0, 1.4, 0.4}]
```

And I have:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
 MeshFunctions -> {ArcTan[#1,#3]&},
 MeshShading -> {Red, Yellow},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ViewPoint -> {3.0, 1.4, 0.4}]
```

Suppose I want to combine both mesh functions. I tried:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {{ArcTan[#1, #3] &}, {#2 &}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Yellow},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 ViewPoint -> {3.0, 1.4, 0.4}]
```

But that didn't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {ArcTan[#1, #3] &, #2 &}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Red, Yellow}, {Blue, Green}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ViewPoint -> {3.0, 1.4, 0.4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @beliarius Nice job! Thanks.